# Is it actually possible to use Firefox mobile remote debuging?

Tags: android, debugging, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Mozzila decided they don't need error console in their mobile browser, so they instead invented "*Remote debugging*", something that would probably be cool if it ever worked. I tried it few times before just for fun, but never got it to connect. Now I really needed and I was also expecting the feature improved over time. Not at all.

#### Enable on Mobile

To enable remote debugging, you're first supposed to allow [USB debugging](http://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) and then remote debugging in Firefox Mobile. These are just two buttons, so it's no problem. My **Firefox Mobile version is 39.0**.

[image: image description]

#### Enable in browser

In browser, as I understand it, WebIDE is used, which is a special Firefox debugger and virtualiser. Can be launched using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. The connected USB device is supposed to appear in menu:

[image: image description]

I was wondering why I see *Install ADB Helper* in menu when it's already installed. It's probably because this:

[image: image description]

I guess Firefox hates me.

#### The question

Since Mozzila obviously disabled their only means of debugging mobile Firefox, I came here to ask for some workaround. With all those mobile web pages I expect lot of you guys know how to debug them. Possible solutions I'm looking for:

1. Debug **over IP** instead of USB. I am much more comfortable with using WiFi than USB.
2. Force Firefox to **enable ADB Helper** even though it's incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get ADB Helper working, update your Firefox desktop version. It looks like you're on 37, which is unsupported, insecure, and ~6 months out of date.
2. Wi-Fi Debugging landed in Firefox 42: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_over_Wifi